# The first function is too slow, what can I do?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

I have a problem. I have two functions, but the first function is too slow, so the second function can't work correctly. I saw that the problem can be solved with async and await, but I don't know how this works. The function submit() is too slow. Can anyone tell me how it works?

This is my code:

```
  submit() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('seller')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: widget.name)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((result) {
        print(result.id + ' --------------------');
        documentID = result.id;
        print(documentID);
      });
    });
    print('test--------------------------');
    addData();
  }

  addData() {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {'name': 'Paul'};
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('seller')
        .document(documentID)
        .collection('test')
        .add(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
submit() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
```